# Using VBA to control a specific program in Windows (Sending keystroke to the program)

Tags: excel, vba, windows, automation

So I have repetitive tasks to do on a program in Windows. I try to do it using VBA and Windows API, to send keystrokes to a program which was already running.

Here is my code for reference (Google Chrome is chosen for illustration only)

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long

Public Sub Automate()
    Dim hwnd As LongPtr
   'There must be Google Chrome opened and having a New Tab as the main tab
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "New Tab - Google Chrome")
    
    If hwnd = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Program window not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    SetForegroundWindow hwnd
    
    AppActivate ("New Tab - Google Chrome")
    
    Application.SendKeys "^h"
End Sub
```

So the problem is the method does not always get the program windows for sending keystrokes. I have to choose the program again to let VBA successfully send keystroke to the program. Is there any reliable way to  send keystrokes to a program without failure. More over, this method require knowledge about the exact windows program name. Is there any way to identify the program by, for example by file location or name in task manager ?

Comment: You can iterate all top level windows with `EnumWindows()` and check their `GetWindowsText` - Text in Title Bar. This way You could use partial matches or RegEx to identify a window.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this function I wrote a while ago, it should also work if a string just partially matches the window title and you can use it without specifying the class name (just don't use the optional parameter).

Also, most of the included API functions are not needed for this function, I'll delete the unnecessary ones when I have time.

```vb
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliSeconds As Long)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As PointAPI) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, lpRect As RECT) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wCmd As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Boolean
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageTimeoutA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal msg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As Any, ByVal fuFlags As Long, ByVal uTimeout As Long, lpdwResult As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hwndParent As LongPtr, ByVal lpEnumFunc As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Boolean
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If
#Else
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "sleep" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
    Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As PointAPI) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessageTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageTimeoutA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Any, ByVal fuFlags As Long, ByVal uTimeout As Long, lpdwResult As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Private Function FindTopLevelWindow(partOfTitleStr As String, _
                          Optional className As String = "§$%³") As LongPtr
#Else
Private Function FindTopLevelWindow(partOfTitleStr As String, _
                           Optional className As String = "§$%³") As Long
#End If
    Const GW_CHILD = 5
    Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
    Dim tLen As Long
    Dim i As Long: i = 0
    
    FindTopLevelWindow = GetWindow(GetDesktopWindow(), GW_CHILD)
    
    Do While FindTopLevelWindow <> 0
        tLen = GetWindowTextLength(FindTopLevelWindow)
        Dim wname As String: wname = Space(tLen)
    
        GetWindowText FindTopLevelWindow, wname, tLen
        
        If InStr(1, wname, partOfTitleStr) > 0 Then
            If className <> "§$%³" Then
                Dim tClassName As String: tClassName = Space(256)
                GetClassName FindTopLevelWindow, tClassName, Len(tClassName)
                
                'Null termination has to be removed:
                If className = left(Trim(tClassName), Len(Trim(tClassName)) - 1) Then
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        FindTopLevelWindow = GetWindow(FindTopLevelWindow, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        
        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 10 = 0 Then DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```